# Jquery chaining hide/show fadein/fadeout

Tags: jquery, function, chaining

this is my first post here so excuse me if I make some mistake. I'm also very new regarding jquery.

So, I've been battling with this jquery code, what I want to do is that each div="step" shows or hides, or fades in or fades out after pressing the buttons.

I've tried chaining the jquery after pressing a button, one div hides and right afterwards the next div shows. I've read a lot regarding this issue and I don't think im making any mistakes and yet it's not working.

Any ideas about what's breaking it?

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnsteps').click(function() {
    $('#step1').hide(1000, function() {
      $("#step2").show(1000, function() {
        $('#btnsteps2').click(function() {
          $('#step2').hide(1000, function() {
            $("#step3").show(1000);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="form">

  <div class="register">
    <!--step1-->
    <div id="step1">
      <p>ARE YOU READY ?</p>
      <button id="btnsteps" type="submit">YES &raquo;</button></div>
    <!--end step 1-->

    <!--step 2-->
    <div id="step2" class="hidden">
      <p>ARE YOU WANT TO JOIN FOR FREE ?</p>
      <button type="submit" id="btnsteps2">YES &raquo;</button></div>
    <!--end step 2-->
    <!--step 3-->
    <div id="step3" class="hidden">
      <p>THEN YOU MUST KNOW</p>
      <button id="btnjoin" type="submit">Join me &raquo;</button></div>
    <!--end step 3-->

  </div>
  <!-- fin register-->



</div>
<!-- fin form-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#step2").hide();
  $("#step3").hide();

  $("#btnsteps").click(function() {
    $("#step1").hide(1000, function() {
      $("#step2").show(1000, function() {});
    });

    $("#btnsteps2").click(function() {
      $("#step2").hide(1000, function() {
        $("#step3").show(1000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but this isnt working neither.

Comment: This is strange, I'm copy-paste'ing the thing off codepen (because it's working) however, it's not working on my end. But at least this solves it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#step1').show();
    $('.btnsteps').click(function() {
       $(this).closest('.stepdiv').next('.stepdiv').show();
       $(this).closest('.stepdiv').hide(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="form">

<div class="register"> 
          <!--step1-->
          <div id="step1" class="stepdiv">
           <p>ARE YOU READY ?</p>
           <button class="btnsteps" type="submit">YES &raquo;</button>
          </div>
          <!--end step 1--> 
           
          <!--step 2-->
          <div id="step2" class="hidden stepdiv">
           <p>ARE YOU WANT TO JOIN FOR FREE ?</p> 
           <button class="btnsteps" type="submit">YES &raquo;</button>       
          </div>
          <!--end step 2--> 
          <!--step 3-->
          <div id="step3"  class="hidden stepdiv">
           <p>THEN YOU MUST KNOW</p>
           <button class="btnsteps" type="submit">YES &raquo;</button>
           </div>
         
          <!--end step 3--> 
        </div>
<!-- fin register-->

        
       
    </div>
<!-- fin form-->
```

Comment: I've just tried it but it didnt work. It's still on step 1 after pressing the button. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Try again, i just send you sample. you have to change id="btnsteps" to class="btnsteps"

Comment: Nope. I've tried doing that too and it didnt work. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnsteps').click(function() {
        $('#step1').hide(1000);
        $("#step2").show(1000);
    });
    $('#btnsteps2').click(function() {
        $('#step2').hide(1000);
        $("#step3").show(1000);
    )};
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But sadly I've tried this solution and it's not working neither. After pressing the button, it's still on step 1.

Comment: don't set submit type of button,like this  `<button id="btnsteps">YES &raquo;</button>`

Comment: Yep just did that, and it's still not working. Thank you for the answer though!